# How to export SQL data records to CSV format using stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms, export-to-csv

Is it possible to export records to csv format using SQL script in stored procedure?

I am trying make job schedule, that will export records into a `.csv` file. I am using SQL Server 2012.

I don't want to make small application for just an exporting. That's why I am trying to make a script and add it in schedule. For example, I have records like

```
EmpID  EmployeeName  TotalClasses 
---------------------------------
01     Zaraath        55
02     John Wick      97
```

File destination location is `D:/ExportRecords/file.csv`

Comment: You can save the query result in CSV in SSMS,

Comment: You make an effort. A trivial search will find many discussions.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS you can save the query result in CSV format.

[image]

Try This Below Query

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO 

declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from DatabaseName..TableName" queryout d:\FileName.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

You have to create Empty `FileName.csv` in `D:\`

Comment: I want by script

Comment: I share the query. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BCP (Bulk Copy Program) the built-in cli for exporting data from SQL Server.  It's low overhead, executes fast, and has lots of feature switches, like -t (which creates CSV file) which make it good for scripting.

Something like this.  The [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) are useful as well

```
BCP dbo.YourTable out D:/ExportRecords/file.csv -c -t
```